# Is it possible to merge several data into one DataFrames from function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, merge

Function uses **name** from loop and prints 10 or more data sets. I want to merge them in one DataFrames write into csv file.

```
def f(name):
        url = "https://apiurl"
        response = requests.get(url, params = {'page': 1}) 
        records = []
        for page_number in range(1, response.json().get("pages")+1):
            response = requests.get(url, params = {'page': page_number})
            records += response.json().get('records')
            df = pd.DataFrame(records)
        return df
```

For loop to the function.

```
for row in valdf.itertuples():
    name = valdf.loc[row.Index, 'Account_ID']
    df1 = f(name)
    print(df1)
```

When I tried df.to_csv('df.csv') it only take last result from loop. Is it possible to merge them in a one DataFrames and export?

Comment: Seems [pd,concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a list outside of the loop and use pd.concat()

```
dfs = []
for row in valdf.itertuples():
    name = valdf.loc[row.Index, 'Account_ID']
    df1 = f(name) 
    dfs.append(df1)

all_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

this assumes the dfs all have the same n dimensions